# Help with probability homework

Tags: probability

I have the following homework problem:

Consider a sample of 10 marbles drawn from a bin that has red and green marbles.
The probability that any marble we draw is red is  $\mu$ = 0,55 (independently, with
replacement). We address the probability of getting no red marbles ($\nu$ = 0, $\nu$ is the frequency of red marbles in the sample) in the
following cases:

1. We draw only one such sample. Compute the probability that  $\nu$ = 0.
2. We draw 1,000 independent samples. Compute the probability that (at least)
   one of the samples has $\nu$ = 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a sample of $10$, drawn with replacement, the probability of no red is $(0.45)^{10}$.

Call this number $p$. We have $p\approx 0.0003405$.

Call the event "no red" by the name $E$. In any trial, the probability that $E$ **doesn't** happen is $1-p$. The probability that if we do the experiment $1000$ times, $E$ never happens is $(1-p)^{1000}$.

So the probability that $E$ happens at least once is $1-(1-p)^{1000}$.

This is approximately $0.28863$.

**Remark:** The mean number of times that $E$ happens in $1000$ trials is $1000p$. The number of trials is large, and the mean is modest, about $0.3405$. In this kind of situation, the binomial distribution is well approximated by the Poisson. so the probability $E$ never happens is approximately $e^{-\lambda}$, where $\lambda=1000p$. That is about $0.7114101$, yielding the approximation $0.28859$ for your probability.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) So the answer to 2. is 1-0.71137 = 0.28863 right? =)

Comment: Yes, thank you again =)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I had edited my answer in case the $0.71137$ caused confusion. But obviously it didn't, you know what's going on.

Comment: Thank you again for more precise answer =) Appreciate your effort!